# wp_enqueue_script & constants?

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script, constants

I'm enqueuing a script:

```
wp_enqueue_script('my-script', MY_SCRIPTS."/my-script.js");
```

How to get MY_SCRIPTS const working in this context?

I know this works:

```
$template_dir = get_bloginfo('template_directory');
wp_enqueue_script('my-script',"$template_dir/my-scripts/my-script.js");
```

But I don't like this approach at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value you pass to wp_enqueue_script should be the URL of the script, not the local file path.

```
wp_enqueue_script('my-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/my-scripts/my-script.js');
```